# ラズベリーパイでPWMで明るさの調節が失敗する

Tags: ruby, raspberry-pi

ラズベリーパイでLEDの点滅までは上手くいったのですが、PWMで明るさの調節をしようとすると失敗します。

以下のコードで初めに点灯・消灯を行いますが、pwmWriteの部分で一切光がつきません。
どこが間違っているのかを調べようにもエラーメッセージ等が出てこず、どうして良いかわからない状態です。

何かアドバイスを頂けないでしょうか。

```
require "wiringpi.rb"
pin = 5
io = WiringPi::GPIO.new
io.mode(pin, OUTPUT)
io.write(pin, 1)
sleep(0.5)
io.write(pin, 0)
io.mode(pin, PWM_OUTPUT)
11.times do
  io.pwmWrite(pin, 1023)
  sleep(0.2)
  io.pwmWrite(pin, 600)
  sleep(0.2)
  io.pwmWrite(pin, 0)
  sleep(0.2)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PWM出力に対応しているのは`ピン1`のみです。

> - **void pinMode (int pin, int mode) ;**
>
> This sets the mode of a pin to either **INPUT**, **OUTPUT**, or **PWM_OUTPUT**. Note that only wiringPi pin 1 (BCM_GPIO 18) supports PWM output.

https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/functions/

Comment: ありがとうございます、無事動かせました。！ GPIOは全て同じ扱いなのだと勘違いしまっていました。